# Could the range of $\sum_{k\geq 1}r^{n(k)} (r\in (\frac{1}{2}, 1))$ be continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $\mathcal{F}_N$ be the set of all strictly increasing sequences of positive integers. For every two $F_1, F_2\in\mathcal{F}_N$, if we use $\delta(F_1,F_2)$ to denote the first $n$-th coordinate where $F_1(n)\neq F_2(n)$, then $d(F_1, F_2) = \exp[-\delta(F_1, F_2)]$ defines a metric on the space $\mathcal{F}_N$. One can observe that $d$ is an ultra-metric because, for each $F_1, F_2, F_3\in\mathcal{F}_N, d(F_1, F_3)\leq \max\Big[ d(F_1, F_2), d(F_2, F_3) \Big]$. Now fix $r\in(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$. My questions are:

1. Will there exists a finite set of positive integers $M$ such that $\sum_{i\in M}r^i = 1$? Does the existence of such a finite set depend on $r$?
2. Notice that we can view $\mathcal{F}_N$ as the family of all **infinite** subset of $\mathbb{N}$ (viewing each element in $\mathcal{F}_N$ as a sequence is more compatible to the given metric). For the fix $r\in(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$, one can observe that the set $\Big\{ \sum_{i\in F}r^i\,\vert\, F\in\mathcal{F}_N \Big\}$ is bounded below by $0$ (which is also the infimum) and bounded above by $\frac{r}{1-r}$. Is the following function surjective?

$$
S_r:\mathcal{F}_N\rightarrow (0, \frac{r}{1-r}], \hspace{0.5cm} F\mapsto \sum_{i\in F}r^i
$$

In particular, I wonder, when **part 1)** is not true for all $r\in(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$, if it is true that, for each $r\in(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$, I can always find $F_r\in\mathcal{F}_N$ such that $S_r(F_r)=1$. One can easily check that $S_r$ is continuous for each $r\in(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$. If I instead let $\mathcal{F}_N$ be the set of all **non-negative** integers, then I suppose $S_{\frac{1}{n}}$ will be  surjective for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$; however, under this assumption, I do not know if $S_r$ will be surjective even when $r\neq\frac{1}{n}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but my current biggest concern is on the those two questions above.

Any hints or thoughts will be appreciated!

Comment: If $r$ is not an algebraic number such finite set $M$ does not exist.  If $r$ is rational such finite set does not exist either.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me the algebraic numbers. Could you explain why your second point is true?

Comment: My solution is wrong, as the continuity fails.  For example ${1\over 2}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty {1\over 2^k}$ is the limit of ${1\over 2} +\sum_{k=n}^\infty {1\over 2^k}$  but ${r^2\over 1-r}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty {r^k}$ is not the limit of ${r} +\sum_{k=n}^\infty {r^k}.$  Please unaccept my answer so I can delete it. Sorry

Comment: Thank you for your pointing out the mistake and your patience. I look forward to seeing your updated answer.

Comment: For the first time I have to thank for unnacepting my post. I wish I could solve your question. It seems very challenging, at least for me. Perhaps someone else in our community gets an idea.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Can you try this one ? I have failed, but the problem is very interesting.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I am sorry for spoiling the answer. I posted the same question in MathOverflow and someone solved this by greedy algorithm. Here is the post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433782

Comment: Thanks for the info. Nice answer.